# Open source alternative to SQLMaestro for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, modeling

I'm looking for oen source alternative to [SQLMaestro for PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/maestro/) because it has visual database designer which not avaliable in pgAdmin which make database desinging so easy.

PS
I'm not sure if this is illegal here but I've to ask about it because google didn't help me for find the alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found awesome tools in [PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools) thank for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) did the trick for me. Runs on Windows, OS X and Linux.